# Convert nested if else from T-SQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a function in SQL Server with nested if and else condition and trying to convert to PostgreSQL Function,

here is the code format. please let me know what would the best way to implement in PostgreSQL.

Please help me out here by providing tour value information.

```
declare 
            @contry             varchar(256)
            @city                     VARCHAR(256), 
            @state                      VARCHAR(256), 
            @age        int,
            @sal        int
            ;

        DECLARE @total VARCHAR(512) = '';

        IF('USA')
           BEGIN
              SET @total = '';
           END;
           ELSE
           BEGIN
              IF(@age < 40)
                 BEGIN
                    SET @total =1000;
                 END;
                 ELSE IF( '  ') AS
                INT))
                 BEGIN
                    SET @total = '';
                 END;
                 ELSE
                 BEGIN
                    IF(@STATE ='NZ')
                        BEGIN
                           SET @total='';
                        END;
                        ELSE
                        BEGIN
                          
                              END;
                        END;
                 END;
           END;
```

Comment: That's not "SQL" - that's T-SQL. Tere is no `IF` in SQL - which is a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CASE` keyword instead of `IF`. When using `CASE` we will not write many `ELSE-IF` keywords and our SQL code will be very simple and readable.

Additionally,
If when my code has many `if` conditions or many `case` conditions then I use the written below method, which is my idea. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE conditions_params (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    param_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    param_value varchar(200) NULL,
    return_value text NULL
);

INSERT INTO conditions_params (param_name, param_value, return_value) 
VALUES('state', 'USA', '0');
INSERT INTO conditions_params (param_name, param_value, return_value) 
VALUES('state', 'NZ', '0');
INSERT INTO conditions_params (param_name, param_value, return_value) 
VALUES('state', 'BK', '');
INSERT INTO conditions_params (param_name, param_value, return_value) 
VALUES('state', 'M1', '1000');
INSERT INTO conditions_params (param_name, param_value, return_value) 
VALUES('state', 'M2', '1000');
INSERT INTO conditions_params (param_name, param_value, return_value) 
VALUES('state', 'SS', 'none');
INSERT INTO conditions_params (param_name, param_value, return_value) 
VALUES('state', 'A1', '1');
INSERT INTO conditions_params (param_name, param_value, return_value) 
VALUES('state', 'A2', '1');
INSERT INTO conditions_params (param_name, param_value, return_value) 
VALUES('state', 'A3', '1');


-- use this SQL code, without using the 9 "IF" keyword 
declare st VARCHAR; --state 
declare total VARCHAR = ''; -- return data 

select 
    return_value into total 
from 
    conditions_params
where 
    param_name = 'state' and 
    param_value = st;
```

If the total variable will be equal to "null", then it means that no conditions were true.

Comment: Hi Thanks for ur response. as per my logic , i need to use CASE or else if condition. is postgresql will support my logic like else if

Comment: any one help on this